# CSVReader doesnt read special letters

Tags: java, csvreader

I want to read data from CSV file.

```
File csvfile = new File("/sdcard/Download/" + returnFileName(Integer.parseInt(year)));
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvfile.getAbsolutePath()));
List<String[]> nextLine = reader.readAll();
```

This is my functon. It reads all data exepct data with special letters like Gdańsk with (ń). It just gives empty string

I expect to get all data even if it has special letters

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem. What is the file encoding? (it works fine with UTF-8) Also are you sure you are reading correct file? Maybe file you are *actually* reading really doesn't have values you expect.

Answer (score 0):

It's all about [character encoding](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Character_encoding) used to store the file contents. The file was probably written in a different encoding than the one you are using to read the file. If you know what encoding was used to write the file you should use the same encoding while reading the file. `FileReader` reader uses the [default platform encoding](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#defaultCharset()) if you do not provide one by means of a dedicated [`FileReader(File, Charset)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/io/FileReader.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.io.File,java.nio.charset.Charset)) constructor:

[The documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/io/FileReader.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.io.File,java.nio.charset.Charset)) is clear about it:

> Decoding from bytes to characters uses either a specified [charset](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) or the [default charset](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#defaultCharset()).

Unfortunately, there's no reliable way to automatically detect the encoding of a text file. The only way is to try the most popular encodings used to write your language diacritical characters and see if the file read operation gives you the expected outcome. You can read more about possible encodings used for Polish alphabet [here](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Polish_alphabet#Computer_encoding).

Comment: Yes it is UTF-8. 

``Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
                File csvfile = new File("/sdcard/Download/" + returnFileName(Integer.parseInt(year)));
                CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvfile.getAbsolutePath(), charset));
                List<String[]> nextLine = reader.readAll();
`
But im recieving an error when i want to implement the Charset

Comment: What error do you have?

Comment: error: no suitable constructor found for FileReader(String,Charset)
                CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvfile.getAbsolutePath(), charset));

Comment: The constructor `FileReader(File, Charset)` was introduced in JDK11. In case you are using an older JDK version then you can use `FileInputStream(InputStream, Charset)` instead.

Comment: Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
                File csvfile = new File("/sdcard/Download/" + returnFileName(Integer.parseInt(year)));
                CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(new FileInputStream(csvfile.getAbsolutePath(), charset)));

Got the same error "no suitable constructor found for FileInputStream(String,Charset)"

Comment: @BartoszBoluk You can use `InputStreamReader` to specify charset: `CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(csvfile), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));`

Comment: @Pshemo still not loading the data with special letters. Maybe i check endcoding wrong. How can i do it for excel file?